# Extract part from a string

Tags: c#, .net, regex

Could someone please explain me how to write regular expressions to extract the "duration" and "time" from given strings?

```
Duration: 00:21:38.97, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2705 kb/s
```

From the first string I want to extract duration `"00:21:38.97"` part.

```
size= 1547kB time=00:01:38.95 bitrate= 128.1kbits/s
```

From the second string I want to extract time `"00:01:38.95"` part.

I've tried

```
Regex.Match(theString, @"\:\s([^)]*)\,\s").Groups[1].Value;
```

Comment: Any reason you can't use `String.Split`? When you are asking about regex you need to supply a number of input and output examples, as there is no way to infer a pattern from a single example.

Comment: What does this have to do with ffmpeg? The output coming from it is not a good reason

Comment: @RohitJain, this is what I have tried so far;

Regex.Match("Duration: 00:21:38.97, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2705 kb/s", @"\:\s([^)]*)\,\s").Groups[1].Value;

Comment: @MiserableVariable, I'm trying to make a progress bar based on the output coming from the ffmpeg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a possible solution:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"(((?<Hour>[0-9]{1,2})[.:](?=[0-9]{2}))?(?<Minute>[0-9]{1,2})[.:])(?<Second>[0-9]{2})[.:](?<Milisecond>[0-9]{2})");

        var string1 = "Duration: 00:21:38.97, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2705 kb/s";
        var string2 = "size= 1547kB time=00:01:38.95 bitrate= 128.1kbits/s ";

        foreach(var match in regex.Match(string1).Captures)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(match.ToString());
        }

        foreach (var match in regex.Match(string2).Captures)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(match.ToString());
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

Output:

```
00:21:38.97
00:01:38.95
```

Comment: Thank you so much Mr. Leniel Macaferi, this is what exactly I was looking for. Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

When you need to write a regex, you need to think about what *describes* the text you're trying to match.

For your first example, two possible descriptions come to mind:

1. "Match a series of four two-digit numbers, separated by colons".
   That would be `@"\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}"` or `@"(?:\d{2}:){3}\d{2}"`.
2. Match any text following after `"Duration: "` until (but not including) the next comma. That would be  `@"(?<=Duration: )[^,]*"`.

Similarly, for your second example, you could write

1. "Match a series of four two-digit numbers, separated by colons (except for the last one which is a dot)": `@"\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{2}"`.
2. Match any text following after `"time="` until (but not including) the next whitespace. That would be  `@"(?<=time=)\S*"`.

Whether any of these actually does what you need it to do depends on the actual data you're encountering. For example, the first regex would find a match in `1234:56:78:9012` (it would match `34:56:78:90` here, which probably is not what you'd want). The second regex would fail on a string like `Duration: 00:21:38.97; start: 0.000000; bitrate: 2705 kb/s` because the separator has changed.

So you need to know exactly what you're looking for; writing a regex is pretty straightforward, then.